# How to express to turn a thing back to its normal / correct position when currently it is "inside-out" or "back to front"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> **[right side up](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/right_1#right_idmg_6)** ​(North American English) with the top part turned to
>   the top; in the correct, normal position
>
> I dropped my toast, but luckily it fell right side up.

---

> **[upside down](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/upside-down_1)**: ​in or into a position in which the top of something is where the bottom is normally found and the bottom is where the top
>   is normally found
>
> The canoe floated upside down on the lake.

---

We have these term in the dictionary "**upside down**" and "**right side up**".

So we can say "*You are holding the bottle **upside down**! Please turn it **right side up***!"

The bottle is held "**upside down**" [image]

---

The bottle is turned "**right side up**" [image]

---

Now, we have "**inside-out**" in the dictionary

> **[inside-out](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/inside_3#inside_idmg_1)**: with the part that is usually inside facing out
>
> You've got your sweater on inside out.
>
> Turn the bag inside out and let it dry.

---

For example, "**He turned his empty pockets inside-out**"

[image]

**How do I ask him to  turn his pockets back to their normal / correct position?**

Do we say "**Please turn the pockets right side in**"? or "**Please turn the pockets outside in**"?

Also

> [back to front](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/back_1#back_idmg_5): ​if you put on a piece of clothing back to front, you
>   make a mistake and put the back where the front should be
>
> I think you've got that sweater on back to front.

---

**This lady is wearing her shirt back to front**

[image]

How to ask her to wear it correctly? "**Please put it on right side front**"?

Comment: For the bottle, you could also say **the right way up**, and for the shirt, **the right way round**.,

Comment: @KateBunting, could I say "please put the shirt on the other way round"?

Comment: Yes, you could.